# Query treating conditions as separate conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I've attached the where condition of my query, where the highlighted part needs to be treated as one. The problem is that when I run the query and the first condition in the parenthesis is satisfied `(ERRORDESC <> 'Zero Accrual' )` or the other `(year(ENDDATE) >= year(RUNDATE))`, it actually treats them as a separate query.
Is there any other way so that I could make the query return results when both conditions have been satisfied and not just the first or the other one?

[image]

PS. this is a stored procedure. the query is inside a string because im concatinating the conditions then executing it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `or` operator. Try below solution

```
and  ((ERRORDESC <> 'Zero Accrual' ) or (year(ENDDATE) >= year(RUNDATE)))
```

Comment: i actually want to treat them both as one condition. i dont know why but the 'and' operator seems not working.

Comment: @BrethrenAdrianne From your description I guess you need `or` instead of `and`

Comment: ok. this is weird. it's working now. can you enlighten me a bit on why i needed to use an 'or' instead of 'and'? seems illogical :(

Comment: `and` says all condition must be true but `or` says one of the condition must be true. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) you can find more information.

Comment: im quite confused because i needed for both of them to be true. :(

Comment: yes, yes it does. I will never gonna understand this weird backend stuff. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @BrethrenAdrianne You have to read about it then you will understand. I'm glad I could help you.